# Perl modulo operator question

Tags: perl, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why does the first example print a wrong result ?

```
perl -le 'print $x = 100*1.15 % 5'
4
perl -le 'print $x = 1000*1.15 % 5'
0
```

Comment: This also happens in PHP. Python says it's 5.0 (yep, % 5 = 5.0)

Comment: @NullUserException: tnanks. python shell's good for testing the results of float numbers arithmetic :-)

Comment: So's ruby. Ruby tells me it's 4.999999

Comment: [This question gets asked over and over again.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-%28eg%2c-19.9499999999999%29-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-%28eg%2c-19.95%29%3f)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of floating point arithmetic.

```
print $x = int(100*1.15);
```

Gives you 114.

Answer (score 5):

Rounding. Keep in mind that computers can't represent actual decimal places perfectly - they approximate. On my computer, `perl -le 'print $x = (100*1.15)-115'` gives the result `-1.4210854715202e-14`, which means that `100*1.15` is almost, but not quite, 115.